# Replace all email addresses after '@' in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, sql-update

I have a list of emails. I want to change all of them to test emails for my test system e.g. sam@gmail.com to sam@test.com. I don't want to use actual emails as those emails are valid and it will be bad for users to receive such email. Is it possible to change all emails at once in a single query? If so, can anyone share? Thanks.

Comment: Do I understand correct that you always want to replace everything between @ and . by "test" for all you addresses? Are you sure this will not "destroy" them by replacing something that shouldn't replaced or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function.

If you need to select only, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '@.*', '@test.com')
FROM tab
```

If instead you want to update the field value, you can use:

```
UPDATE tab
SET email = REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '@.*', '@test.com');
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1c3fea0ab2f5295c5523cbd13a67f280).